# details of request.getSession() statement?

Tags: java, http, session, servlets

I understand that if we use the following statement

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
```

Will create the Unique session id, Create Cookie and associate Cookie with the Session id.

and helps the container to keep track and identify the clients.

Yes, My question, is there a possibility for me to see the cookie header and Unique Id created by this statement `request.getSession()?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can retrieve a [HTTP Header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_headers) using
[HttpServletRequest.getHeader](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getHeader%28java.lang.String%29).

Although a session can be created by calling `HttpServletRequest.getSession(true)`
it's rather done by the webcontainer. As edl already wrote `HttpServletRequest.getSession().getId()` returns the session id.

Answer (score 3):

You can see it using any HTTP header tracker tool. [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) for example shows the headers in the *Net* panel. Here's a screenshot ([click here for full size](https://tweakers.net/ext/f/FyyWop3fRWFENHLFqf969xTg/full.png)):

[image]

Any newly created cookie will appear as `Set-Cookie` header in the response. The client will send the same value back as `Cookie` header in the subsequent requests in the same session so that the server can identify the client session. For a JSP/Servlet webapplication, your interest is the cookie with the name `JSESSIONID`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use session.getId() for the ID I believe. Not sure about the header.

Answer (score 0):

I found more information in the following URL 
http://www.javacertifications.net/javacert/session.jsp